# Best SQL Server 2005 database transfer method

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

We currently have a Live and Dev environment within our offices, at regular intervals we need to move the live DB to Dev to make sure data is updated for the dev team to work with.

However the live DB is becoming very difficult to manage as its almost hit 100Gb, we currently run a DB backup, copy the file to the other server and restore it. however this is becoming a major headache that can take upwards of 4 - 5 hours.

does anyone have any good recommendations for how we can move the DB in a more efficient manor?

We are using MS SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to update your dev server from the production is to implement a shipping logs strategy.  Perform an incremental backup of your production database daily and place the incremental log in a location where the development server can see it.  Then once a week take all the incremental backups (there should be 5) and increment the development database to make it look like the production.  The process can be automated with sql server tools out there if you want it to, or you can write a little program that will generate the scripts for you from the file names in the directory where you put the log files.  After you do the operation a few times and see the TSQL that SQL server will generate for you each time, you will get a good idea how to write the script generator utility.  You can even automate the restore process to your dev box with the same utility, just connect to the dev server and run the scripts that it generates and then automate the running of the utility.  Most programmers could whip up this utility in a day or two at best as long as they have a decent understanding of sql server and tsql.

You have other options as well, but this one would probably solve most of your issues

1. You get incremental backups of your production database in addition to your full backups that you may or may not do.
2. The utility you write will save time and automate the process all you have to do is check that it was successful or not and you have the utility email you the success/failure.  If you are cloud based use an amazon tool for email, or if you azure based, use sendgrid.com.
3. Your time for producing the utility is not great.